# Get FormData's raw POST body string

Tags: javascript, http-post

Mozilla says about the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) type:

> The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. **It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".**

(Emphasis mine.)

So why do they tell that to me? I haven't found any way to actually see the POST body string data that is sent through an XMLHttpRequest using a FormData object, other than the Firefox F12 console in the network inspection tab. If they think it's important to me to know the wire format this type uses, then where can I retrieve the data so that it makes any difference?

What I want is to see this string in my JavaScript code. Or better yet, only its length. I need this to check whether the server-side limits will be exceeded by this POST request and tell the user before the uploaded bandwidth and the time it takes are wasted.

Answer (score 0):

> So why do they tell that to me?

It's relevant for ensuring that the server-side code can process the submitted data correctly.

> What I want is to see this string in my JavaScript code. Or better yet, only its length.

This is not information the `FormData` API makes available.

That is probably only relevant if you are uploading actual files, consider testing their size directly (with the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)) instead.

Comment: Plus the other contents of the form, if any, and the metadata that seems to be around 600 bytes per (file) field. It's not the most precise thing to try to count it manually.